# Asynchronous sockets with begin/end and a state machine loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, socket

Disclaimer: I am a C++ guy, so my C# is not even close. Therefore some review might be helpful.

Here is my 4th attempt at a client using asynchronous sockets. Please give feedback.

The hardest part of this endeavour is synchronizing what can happen and when it can happen. Some examples I had to tackle in the debugger:

1. If the client cannot connect, how does startup alert the caller while the state machine loop is trying to reconnect? They both can't fight over state.
2. When we disconnect and there is an outstanding call to receive, how can it safely finish and how do we control if another call to receive should occur or not?
3. What happens if we pull the plug after calling send but before it completes?

I found making a looping thread with a state machine that included an error state took care of a lot, but startup and shutdown had to be handled a little differently. I think I took care of all problems. Tests seemed to work OK.

I wonder how others would go about it. A lot of example code I found on the web simply doesn't handle errors or seems to care about cases like those I mentioned, but that is the hardest part.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    public class Client : IDisposable
    {
        static private ulong _lastId = 1;
        private ulong  _id;
        private bool   _disposed;

        protected class ReceiveContext
        {
            public const int _bufferSize = 1024;
            public byte[] _buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];               // Contains bytes from one receive
            public StringBuilder _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();   // Contains bytes for multiple receives in order to build message up to delim
        };

        protected enum ConnectionState
        {
            DISCONNECTED
          , LOGGING_IN
          , CONNECTED
          , ERROR
          , SHUTTING_DOWN
          , SHUTDOWN
        };

        protected string   _host;
        protected int      _port;
        protected TimeSpan _timeout;
        protected TimeSpan _reconnectAttemptInterval;
        protected string   _sessionId;
        protected Socket   _socket;
        protected object   _lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps;
        protected int      _numOutstandingAsyncOps;
        protected int      _connectionState;

        /// <summary>
        /// Manages the state machine that is our connection state
        /// Issues Connect, Disconnect, and Receive calls
        /// </summary>
        protected Thread   _processingThread;

        /// <summary>
        /// Startup should not return until we are connected and logged in, or it has failed in the attempt for the duration of the timeout
        /// </summary>
        protected ManualResetEvent _connectedEvent;

        /// <summary>
        /// We need a signalling mechanism outside of the connection state, because we do not want
        /// Startup, Shutdown, and the ProcessingThread competing to set the state.
        /// This flag is set from the thread calling Startup and Shutdown,
        /// while ConnectionState is set from the Processing thread or async send/receive calls and callbacks resulting from them
        /// </summary>
        protected ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent;

        BlockingCollection<string> _messageQueue;

        public Client(string host, int port, string sessionId, TimeSpan timeoutMilliseconds, TimeSpan reconnectAttemptInterval)
        {
            _id                         = _lastId++;
            _disposed                   = false;
            _host                       = host;
            _port                       = port;
            _sessionId                  = sessionId;
            _timeout                    = timeoutMilliseconds;
            _reconnectAttemptInterval   = reconnectAttemptInterval;
            _socket                     = null;
            _lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps = new object();
            _numOutstandingAsyncOps     = 0;
            _connectionState            = (int)ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED;
            _processingThread           = new Thread(ProcessingThreadProc);
            _connectedEvent             = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            _shutdownEvent              = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            _messageQueue               = new BlockingCollection<string>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if(_disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (disposing)
            {
                Shutdown();
                _messageQueue.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Coming up with names that don't match the type is annoying
        /// </summary>
        protected ConnectionState ConnectionStateProperty
        {
            get { return (ConnectionState)_connectionState; }
            set { Interlocked.Exchange(ref _connectionState, (int)value); }
        }


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void Startup()
        {
            if (_processingThread.IsAlive)
            {
                // Error
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Client #{0} Call to Startup, but processing thread is already started"));
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Starting up.", _id));

            // We want this call to be synchronous, so wait until we are actually connected to return
            // That way, the caller will not start trying to send data until we connect
            _connectedEvent.Reset();
            _processingThread.Start();

            if (_connectedEvent.WaitOne(_timeout))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Started.", _id));
            }
            else
            {
                _shutdownEvent.Set();
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Client #{0} Startup timed out.", _id));
            }
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void Shutdown()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Shutting Down...", _id));

            // Signal out processing thread that we want to shutdown
            _shutdownEvent.Set();

            // Wait for the thread to complete
            if (_processingThread.IsAlive)
            {
                _processingThread.Join();
            }

            // Done
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Shutdown Complete...", _id));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        protected void ProcessingThreadProc()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Processing Thread";

                while(!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
                {
                    switch (ConnectionStateProperty)
                    {
                        case ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED:
                            {
                                // Connect to the server
                                if (!Connect())
                                {
                                    // Try again, after a little wait, until we connect
                                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(_reconnectAttemptInterval);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Start reading from the socket
                                    lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
                                    {
                                        ReceiveContext context = new ReceiveContext();
                                        _numOutstandingAsyncOps = 1;
                                        _socket.BeginReceive(context._buffer, 0, ReceiveContext._bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), context);
                                    }

                                    // Successfully connected
                                    ConnectionStateProperty = ConnectionState.LOGGING_IN;
                                }

                                break;
                            }

                        case ConnectionState.LOGGING_IN:
                            {
                                // Send the Login request
                                string loginRequest = string.Format("loginstuff{0}", _sessionId);
                                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginRequest);

                                lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
                                {
                                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Sending Login Request: {1}"
                                                            , _id, loginRequest));

                                    ++_numOutstandingAsyncOps;
                                    _socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), _socket);
                                }

                                ConnectionStateProperty = ConnectionState.CONNECTED;

                                // Signal Startup(), if it happend to be waiting
                                _connectedEvent.Set();

                                break;
                            }

                        case ConnectionState.ERROR:
                            {
                                // If anything went wrong we are going to go to the disconnected state which will cause a reconnection on the next loop iteration
                                Disconnect();
                                ConnectionStateProperty = ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED;

                                break;
                            }

                        case ConnectionState.CONNECTED:
                            {
                                // TODO - We don't wan't to keep looping with no yield
                                //        We should wait to do the next iteration until 
                                //        A) There is an item on the queue to be processed or
                                //        B) The connection state has changed
                                //        Currently, I only wait on A and we are polling for B
                                string message;
                                if( !_messageQueue.TryTake(out message, _timeout) )
                                {
                                    // Timed out
                                    // Nothing to process, go on to the next iteration in order to handle connection status changes
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                                    {
                                        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Processed Received Data: {1}"
                                                                , _id, message));
                                    }
                                }

                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }

                // We were signalled to shutdown
                // Disconnect the socket
                ConnectionStateProperty = ConnectionState.SHUTTING_DOWN;
                Disconnect();
                ConnectionStateProperty = ConnectionState.SHUTDOWN;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Unhandled exception caught in processing thread. Exception: {1}"
                                       , _id, e.ToString()));
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Processing Thread exiting."
                                    , _id));
        }

        public void MakeRequest(string thingy)
        {
            if (ConnectionStateProperty != ConnectionState.CONNECTED)
            {
                // Error - Cannot log in while not connected
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Client #{0} MakeRequest was called for thingy{1}, but client is not connected."
                                                           , _id, thingy));
            }

            string message = string.Format("requeststuff{0}", thingy);
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Sending Request: {1}"
                                       , _id, message));

                ++_numOutstandingAsyncOps;
                _socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), _socket);
            }
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        protected bool Connect()
        {
            Disconnect();

            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(_host);
            IPAddress[] ipV4Addresses = ipHostInfo.AddressList.Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToArray();
            IPAddress[] ipV6Addresses = ipHostInfo.AddressList.Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6).ToArray();
            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipV4Addresses[0], _port);

            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _socket.ReceiveTimeout = _timeout.Milliseconds;
            _socket.SendTimeout    = _timeout.Milliseconds;

            try
            {
                _socket.Connect(endpoint);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Error
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught while attempting to Connect. Exception: {1}"
                                        , _id, e.ToString()));
                return false;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} connected to: {1}", _id, _socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));
            return true;
        }

        protected void Disconnect()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Disconnecting...", _id));

            // We need to wait here until all outstanding async operations complete
            // In order to avoid getting 'Object was disposed' exceptions in those async ops that use the socket
            lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
            {
                while (_numOutstandingAsyncOps > 0)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps);
                }

                if (_socket != null)
                {
                    if (_socket.Connected)
                    {
                        _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    }

                    _socket.Close();
                    _socket = null;
                }
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Disconnected...", _id));
        }

        protected void OnReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            ReceiveContext context = (ReceiveContext)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            string data = null;

            try
            {
                int bytesReceived = _socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(context._buffer, 0, bytesReceived);

                // If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received,
                // the EndReceive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes
                if (bytesReceived > 0)
                {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = context._stringBuilder.Append(data);

                    int index = -1;
                    do
                    {
                        index = stringBuilder.ToString().IndexOf("#");
                        if (index != -1)
                        {
                            string message = stringBuilder.ToString().Substring(0, index + 1);
                            stringBuilder.Remove(0, index + 1);

                            if (!_messageQueue.TryAdd(message, _timeout))
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Timed out while attempting to queue Received Data: {1}"
                                                        , _id, message));
                            }
                        }
                    } while (index != -1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Error
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught OnReceive. Exception: {1}"
                                        , _id, e.ToString()));

                ConnectionStateProperty = ConnectionState.ERROR;
            }
            finally
            {
                lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
                {
                    --_numOutstandingAsyncOps;
                    Monitor.Pulse(_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps);
                }
            }

            // Issue the next async receive
            if (ConnectionStateProperty == ConnectionState.CONNECTED)
            {
                lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ++_numOutstandingAsyncOps;

                        ReceiveContext newContext = new ReceiveContext();
                        _socket.BeginReceive(newContext._buffer, 0, ReceiveContext._bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), newContext);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        // Error
                        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught OnReceive. Exception: {1}"
                                                , _id, e.ToString()));

                        --_numOutstandingAsyncOps;
                        ConnectionStateProperty = ConnectionState.ERROR;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void OnSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                int bytesSent = _socket.EndSend(asyncResult);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught OnSend. Exception: {1}"
                                        , _id, e.ToString()));

                ConnectionStateProperty = ConnectionState.ERROR;
            }
            finally
            {
                lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
                {
                    --_numOutstandingAsyncOps;
                    Monitor.Pulse(_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string       server            = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
            int          port              = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]);
            int          numClients        = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["numberOfClients"]);
            TimeSpan     clientLifetime    = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientLifetime"]);
            TimeSpan     timeout           = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timeout"]);
            TimeSpan     reconnectInterval = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reconnectInterval"]);
            List<string> clientIds         = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("clientIds") as List<string>;

            try
            {
                Task[] tasks = new Task[numClients];
                for(int count = 0; count < numClients; ++count)
                {
                    var copyOfcount = count;
                    tasks[count] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Client client = new Client(server, port, clientIds[copyOfcount], timeout, reconnectInterval);
                                client.Startup();
                                client.MakeRequest("Request");

                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(clientLifetime);

                                client.Shutdown();
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Caught an exception in task procedure. Exception: {0}"
                                                       , e.ToString()));
                            }
                        });
                }
                Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Caught an exception in main. Exception: {0}"
                                      , e.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```